# Is it possible to move Outlook folders using Win32::OLE?

Tags: perl, win32ole

I have manage to add folders in Outlook, but can't work out how to move them. The code I have does not throw out any warnings and does not move the folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

# use existing instance if Outlook is already running, or launch a new one
  my $Outlook;
eval {$Outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')};
die "Outlook not installed" if $@;
unless (defined $Outlook) {
  $Outlook = Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
    or die "Oops, cannot start Outlook";
}
my $namespace = $Outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");

#my $Folder = $namespace->Folders("backupadmin")->Folders(
    # "Inbox")->Folders->Add("test");

my $Folder = $namespace->Folders("backupadmin")->Folders(
     "Inbox")->Folders("test")->MoveTo("test1");
```

Comment: The Outlook VB namespace looks pretty dicey; is your goal to rename the folder, or re-parent it?  If the goal is naming, something like `...->Folders("test")->Name = "test1"` may work (or something similar using proper syntax like `setName`, etc.).  [Renaming reference](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/rename-folder-outlook-inbox-t3031265.html)

Comment: More correctly, `my $Folder = $namespace->Folders("backupadmin")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders("test")->{"Name"} = "test1";` (again assuming that the intent is to rename the folder, not re-parent it), or `...->Folders("test")->SetProperty('Name', "test1")`

Comment: Note that there are other comments out there suggesting that once a rename like this has been applied, there must be a refresh to see the results as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the popular Outlook Redemption library, you can retrieve a RDO Folder object for the folder you want to move and then call the `MoveTo` method with the destination RDO folder as the parameter. For some sample Perl code, you can reference the `Email::PST::Win32` CPAN module which uses `Win32::OLE` and Outlook Redemption to access RDO Folder objects.

Outlook Redemption: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

RDO Folder with MoveTo Method: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdofolder.htm

Email::PST::Win32: https://metacpan.org/release/Email-PST-Win32